# NAudio UnspecifiedError when calling .StartRecording()

Tags: c#, audio, google-cloud-platform, naudio

I'm receiving the following `UnspecifiedError` when reaching the `waveIn.StartRecording()` method on an `NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent` object instance:

> NAudio.MmException: 'UnspecifiedError calling waveInOpen'

The applicable NAudio code is as follows:

```
var waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 1);

waveIn.StartRecording(); // Here's where the Exception is thrown
```

As it's an UnspecifiedError, I don't have much to go off of. Here's what I've tried so far in my troubleshooting:

**Headsets**

- Using a line-in 3.5mm microphone
- Using a gaming headset microphone

**NAudio versions via Nuget**

- version 1.9.0 (published in April of 2019)
- version 1.8.5 (published in October of 2018)
- version 1.8.4 (published in December of 2017)

**DeviceNumber**

- 0 (only value that does not throw a BadDeviceId Exception)
- 1, 2, 3 (all of which throw a BadDeviceId Exception)

**Parameter Testing of `NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat()`**

**Param1:** Sample Rate
- 16000 (as it is the "default" value contained inside the Google Cloud sample code - info at the bottom of this post)
- 44100 (the truly defacto sample rate, if this doesn't work will any sample rate?)

**Param2:** Bits
- I tried supplying the 3 parameter overload where I supplied 16 bits explicitly, still to no avail

**Param3:** Channels
- 1 (should be correct given both of my mics are mono inputs)
- 2 (tested for good measure)

And lastly, I've also tried entirely commenting out the `waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(...);` line of code, which uses the default new instance of `WaveFormat`, verified via a `Console.WriteLine()` to be 16 bit / 8kHz / 1 channel. But still to no avail.

Thanks for the help.

---

**Update:** TLDR - Not influenced by GCP.

I am moving all information related to Google Cloud down here, as it provides some contextual information, but has been demonstrably proven to not directly influence the NAudio error I am receiving.

I'm trying to get the Google Cloud Speech to Text streaming audio functionality working. I have the `public static async Task<object> StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(int seconds)` function defined as can be found in [Google's Cloud docs here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-csharp).

In a separate async function, I run the following line of code, which contains the code that calls `waveIn.StartRecording()`.

```
object r = await StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(15);
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the exception without any Google Cloud Speech code involved? If so, it's probably worth doing so and providing a [mcve] in the question. (It sounds like this probably occurs before any RPCs, so I *suspect* it's not the speech library, but it would be good to have confirmation.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have verified that this is reproducible with only the NAudio code at the bottom of this question. The Google Cloud Speech code contains the code I posted (along with a handler function it attaches), but the root problem necessarily has to be inside NAudio without Google Cloud in light of the minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: Right. I'd personally suggest removing all the GCP parts at this point - they may be putting off anyone who knows about NAudio, but not about GCP.

Comment: I have now also tested a handful of different parameter values into the `WaveFormat()` method. I am updating the question to detail these tests, but in short I've tried `44100` for the sample rate in addition to the "default" `16000` that ships with the Google Cloud code example, as well as explicitly passing 16 bits and passing 1 & 2 for channels (though 1 should be the correct value as both mics I own are mono).

Comment: I've updated the question to reframe the issue centrally on NAudio, not GCP.

Comment: A few questions. Does your computer definitely have a soundcard? Is it a virtual machine or a remote desktop connection? What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @MarkHeath Yep, has a soundcard. Not a virtual machine or remote connection, just my local desktop. Running Windows 10.

Comment: OK, very odd then, especially given you've also tried 44.1kHz.

Comment: @MarkHeath I would agree

Comment: I haven't read the entire question, but just wanted to say that my solution to `NAudio.MmException: 'UnspecifiedError calling waveInOpen'` problem was to go to "Windows - Settings - Privacy - Microphone" Make sure "Allow apps to access your mic" is [ON]. In case this might help someone. Found solution [here](https://forums.radioreference.com/threads/996p2-freescan-recording-error.378353/)